# What do you call the conical end of a ballpoint pen?

Tags: word-request

You know the conical end of a ballpoint pen that holds the ball inside the end of the conical shaped end of the ballpoint? Is there a name for the conical end? I am thinking it has a name, but I never learned what the name was. Does it also come with several names? If it's the case, what are they?

Comment: Why do you think it has a name. Are you looking for a technical word used in the pen making industry.  Does it have to be specific to ballpoint pens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Colloquially I'd call that the *tip* of the pen.
There may be a technical term for it, but that's a question for a different StackExchange site.

Answer (score 0):

From Merriam-Websters's definition of [*ballpoint pen*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ballpoint):

> : a pen having as the writing point a small rotating metal ball that inks itself by contact with an inner magazine

Note that the definition uses the phrase *writing point*, which makes sense. So, really, the end of a *ballpoint pen* is its *point*.